# List the names of all the classes within a VS2008 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, class, list

Is there a quick & dirty way of obtaining a list of all the classes within a Visual Studio 2008 (c#) project? There are quite a lot of them and Im just lazy enough not to want to do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the "Class View" dialogue (View -> Class View or Ctrl+W, C) you can get a list of all of the classes in your project which you can then select and copy to the clipboard. The copy will send the fully qualified (i.e. with complete namespace) names of all classes that you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using **[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)** to generate documentation from the XML comments in my projects - a byproduct of this is a nice, hyperlinked list of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write an XSL/XSLT to display only the class names from the XML generated by the XML documentation, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably build the assembly, and then use reflection to iterate over all the exported types... If you want some sample code you can find inspiration in http://www.timvw.be/presenting-assemblytypepicker/.